# Starcraft 2 2v2 Strategies

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do team tactics differ from 1v1 tactics in Starcraft II?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4007/how-do-team-tactics-differ-from-1v1-tactics-in-starcraft-ii)

Are there any good strategies for a pair (or more) of players to use? Obviously rushing is better if you both do it, but what other things can you try? Unit synergies? One player building army and other just worrying about economy?

Comment: See also/possible duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4007/how-do-team-tactics-differ-from-1v1-tactics-in-starcraft-ii

Comment: Why was this closed? This is not a duplicate. I can think of multiple answers that do NOT fit well into the assumed "duplicate" thread.

For example: T&Z 10 pool, with reapers against any Protoss opponents is godly.