# What are some high level strategies for 2v2's?

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do team tactics differ from 1v1 tactics in Starcraft II?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4007/how-do-team-tactics-differ-from-1v1-tactics-in-starcraft-ii)

I am getting pretty good at 1 v 1 matches. I scout well and counter well (<3 terran).

However I find countering a lot more difficult when playing 2 v 2's. There are just so many more variables to account for when making that initial plan.

so what are some good approaches for playing 2 v 2's effectively?

Comment: The game is balanced around 1v1 play, and 2v2 play suffers for it.  It is much more difficult to counter many 2v2 strategies, which is why you're probably having so much more difficulty.

Comment: See also: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4007/how-do-team-tactics-differ-from-1v1-tactics-in-starcraft-ii

Comment: Nice I didnt see that post. 2 v 2's have a lot wider range of potential strategies which makes it harder to formulate a plan.

Comment: @StrixVaria - so, isn't this question a duplicate?

Comment: @ripper The other question is asked from the reverse perspective.  I don't know if that's enough to differentiate them, but I don't see a pressing need to close this one this instant.

Comment: I agree that this question seems to cover the same ground as the other one, but I feel like the comparison question could use a stronger, more in-depth answer to help cover the subject matter better. I've placed a bounty to see if that helps to solve this problem.

Comment: @Robotsushi: http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Category:Team_Strategies